# Example of atoms with respect to $ \mu$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I was reading the document [ATOMICITY RELATED TO NON-ADDITIVE
INTEGRABILITY](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05330.pdf) and came across this example about atoms relative to a measure:

Let $T$ be a countable set, $\mathscr{A} = \{A\subseteq T\colon A \text{ is finite or } A^c \text{ is finite} \}$ and $\mu: \mathscr{A}\to [0,\infty)$ definided for every $A\in \mathscr{A}$ by
$$
\mu (A)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0, & \text { if } A \text { is finite } \\
1, & \text { if } A^{c} \text { is finite. }
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then every set $A\in \mathscr{A}$, such that $A^c$ is finite, is an atom with respect of $\mu$.

But I can't see how it is concluded that every set $A\in \mathscr{A}$, such that $A^c$ is finite, is an atom with respect of $\mu$, can someone help me?

Comment: Comments:  1. "Countable" seems to mean "countably infinite".   2. $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-additive (so not a measure).

Answer (score 4):

If $A^c$ is finite, then $A$  must be infinite. Otherwise, $T=A\cup A^c$ would be finite. So $\mu(A)=1$. Now, if $E\subseteq A$ and $E\in\mathcal{A}$, then, by the latter condition, $E$ is finite and satisfies $\mu(E)=0$, or $E^c$ is finite, which , again. implies that $E$ is infinite and $\mu(E)$. So either $\mu(E)=\mu(A)$ or $\mu(E)=0$ for all $E\subseteq A$ with $E\in\mathcal{A}$, which is exactly the definition of $A$ being an atom.